# What does a blue dot beneath the Visual Studio breakpoint mean?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

While debugging a combined c++ c# project (c# loading a c++ dll) I'm sometimes getting this small blue dot beneath the currently hit breakpoint: [image: Blue dot beneath breakpoint]

What does that dot want to tell me?

Comment: does your application multithreaded?

Comment: Yes, I think it does. I figured out, the point always appears on the first hit after the Studio breaks at another (worker-)thread

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you app is multithreaded and if hovering over break point gives you message is like "The process or thread has changed since the last step" it means that this break point is applied to more then one thread, not just thread creator. After you press F5 another threads will run and they will hit your break point which can confuse you. In order to give you some kind of warning visual studio give you blue dot beneath. So sometimes it can be useful to freeze other threads in order to debug method.